# sitemap magento lastmod

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

In order to fix the fact that magento puts the current date into the sitemap's lastmod field. This leads to poor crawl rates, I modified the date in Sitemap.php ( app/code/local/Mage/Sitemap/Model/Sitemap.php) like this:

```
    /*
     * Generate categories sitemap
     **/

    $changefreq = (string)Mage::getStoreConfig('sitemap/category/changefreq', $storeId);
    $priority   = (string)Mage::getStoreConfig('sitemap/category/priority', $storeId);
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sitemap/catalog_category')->getCollection($storeId);
    foreach ($collection as $item) {
        $xml = sprintf('<url><loc>%s</loc><lastmod>%s</lastmod><changefreq>%s</changefreq><priority>%.1f</priority></url>',
            htmlspecialchars($baseUrl . $item->getUrl()),
            substr(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($item->getId())->getUpdatedAt(),0,10),  //---> here the changes
            $changefreq,
            $priority
        );
        $io->streamWrite($xml);
    }
```

that's works but I noticed some lastmod are empty for some url in my sitemap.xml (www.edenglamode.com/sitemap.xml)
so google complained about that, I tried some modifications on product and regenerated the sitemap but no way

```
<url>
 <loc>
   http://www.edenglamode.com/robe-courte-sexy-bustier-avec-ceinture.html
 </loc>
   <lastmod/>
   <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>
  <priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
```

Could you help me to fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the product lastmod time is NULL then you should load the product, add DATE as lastmod, save the product and write out DATE into your XML. Next time round it won't have the problem as lastmod exists. It will then be able to write out the sitemap entry without having to wait an age for Magento to load 'n' save the product.

Can I enquire as to how you ended up with no lastmod times? Did you import the products en-masse and not open them in admin?

Comment: I have so many products without lastmod :-( I just modified the Sitemap file few days ago, my products were already there, I cannot load them one by one. I have to figure out the best way to do that. if I use the default Sitemap file, I have all lastmod date but with magento current date instead. I noticed also that all products created before changing to the last version has this lake of lastmod